# Unable to display belonging between two objects in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-associations

I'm trying to display every objets that a dresseur own but when I do in

**app/views/dresseurs/index.html.erb**

```
<% @dresseurs.each do |dresseur| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= dresseur.objets%></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

It displays on my view

```
<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy_Objet:0x007fc4d34c1f90>
```

**app/controllers/dresseur_controller.rb**

```
def index
  @dresseurs = Dresseur.all
  @objet = Objet.all
end
```

**app/models/dresseur.rb**

```
class Dresseur < ActiveRecord::Base

  #Validations
   before_save { self.email = email.downcase}
   validates :pseudo, presence: true, length: {maximum:13}
   VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
   validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },length {maximum:50}, uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false}
    validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }

   #Associations
   has_and_belongs_to_many :objets
  end
```

**app/models/objet.rb**

```
class Objet < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :dresseurs
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you are having relation between `Dresseur` and `Objet` model having `has_and_belongs_to_many` so `dresseur.objets` will return `<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy_Objet` only(array).

so,you should loop again `dresseur.objets` this and you should display.

```
<% @dresseurs.map do |dresseur| %>
 <tr>
  <td><% dresseur.objets.each do |obj|%>
   <%=obj%>
  <%end%></td>
 </tr>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `map` instead

```
<% @dresseurs.map do |dresseur| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= dresseur.objets%></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: It still displays the same thing

Comment: @VincentTaing What is the version of your Rails?

Answer (score 0):

Because each `dresseur` has many `objets`, what you get is the reference to the `objets` container. Depending on what you want to do, you might want to do something like this:

```
<% @dresseurs.each do |dresseur| %>
  <tr>
    <% dresseur.objets.each do |objet|
      <td><%= objet.id %></td>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```